# this.$apollo always undefined

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to use `apollo` (+ vue, django) but for some reason it won't get loaded/used in a component,`this.$apollo` is always `undefined`.

```
<script>
import { GET_ALL_USERS_QUERY } from '../js/graphql/queries/userQueries.js'
export default {
  name: 'GraphQLTest',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      loading: true
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.loading = true
    this.users = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: GET_ALL_USERS_QUERY
    })
    this.loading = false
  }
}
</script>


  [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined"
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { router } from './routes.js'
import store from './store.js'
import { createProvider } from './apollo.js'

import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false


new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  provide: createProvider(),
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

apollo.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'

// Install the vue plugin
Vue.use(VueApollo)

// Name of the localStorage item
const AUTH_TOKEN = 'jwt-token'

// Config
const defaultOptions = {
  httpEndpoint: '/graphql',
  wsEndpoint: null,
  tokenName: AUTH_TOKEN,
  persisting: false,
  websocketsOnly: false,
  ssr: false
}

// Call this in the Vue app file
export function createProvider (options = {}) {
  // Create apollo client
  const { apolloClient, wsClient } = createApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options
  })
  apolloClient.wsClient = wsClient

  // Create vue apollo provider
  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        loadingKey: 'loading',
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
      }
    },
    errorHandler (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
    }
  })

  return apolloProvider
}

// Manually call this when user log in
export async function onLogin (apolloClient, token) {
  localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (login)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}

// Manually call this when user log out
export async function onLogout (apolloClient) {
  localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (logout)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}
```

Why is `apollo` never loaded? something missing in the config?

[**edit**: same thing happens when following the tutorial : ]

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import { router } from './routes.js'
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost"
import VueApollo from "vue-apollo"

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/"
  })
})


Vue.use(VueApollo)
new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
  provide: apolloProvider.provide(),
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: @Daniel, I've added the apollo.js config. But I tried exactly as in the docs as well (even using the `boost` shortcut), all with the same failed result.

Comment: @DanielRearden yes. you can see it is there, right?

Comment: So what is `provide`?

Comment: it is one of the many variations I found in different tutorials, because the version in the official docs didn't work either. for example, this fails in the same way: https://dpaste.org/kp7h

Answer (score -2):

if you created your VUE project using vue-cli > 3  this will cause the issue with this.$apollo equal to undefined.

Comment: Simply stating the source of the problem is generally far less helpful than suggesting a solution. Please consider adding a potential fix for the problem to your answer. Without one, your answer would be better suited as a comment on the original question.